# css responsive dropdown menu - more levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have responsive dropdown menu.

[image: drop-down] [image: mobile]

I want to open submenu on hover/toogle. It work to 2nd submenu.

But when I hover to 2nd submenu **all other** submenus will open. How to prevent this to menu will work correctly?

### Question:

How to open menu on hover/toggle in deeper sub-menus ?
(prevent to open all submenus)

### JSFIDDLE:

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/BrPeY/)

### HTML:

```
    <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first activeSelected"><a href="#">Menu 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 0</a>        
            <ul class="level1">
                <li class="first"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="level2">
                        <li class="first"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>        
                            <ul class="level3">
                                <li class="first"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>        
                                    <ul class="level4">
                                        <li class="first"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 0</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu 0</a></li>
    </ul>
```

### CSS:

```
body, nav {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

a {text-decoration: none;}
ul, li, a  {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.toggleMenu {
    display: none;
    background: #111;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    background:#111;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.menu:after {
    clear: both;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.menu a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.menu > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.menu li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.menu > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.menu li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.menu li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #222;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
}
.menu li li li a {
    background:#333;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
}
.menu li li li li a {
    background:#444;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
.menu li li li li li a {
    background:#555;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .menu > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .menu li li .parent {
        background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu > li.hover > ul , .menu li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

### JS:

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 480) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".menu").hide();
        } else {
            $(".menu").show();
        }
        $(".menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".menu li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    } 
    else if (ww >= 480) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu").show();
        $(".menu li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".menu li a").unbind('click');
        $(".menu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware that more level menu is not good in common, so that 4th level submenu is max :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS please change

```
.menu li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

to

```
.menu li li.hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

This seems to work but need more fine tuning. As far as I have been able to understand the problem. This could be related to accessing the immediate child.

Comment: this `edit` also add to media-query section and it work as charm ... my second problem is overflow ... how to apply `overflow: hidden;` for each `li` element without effecting whole menu